# Use of varchar variable in a stored procedure to write a table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE @server_nm varchar(100)

IF (@@SERVERNAME LIKE 'DEVABCD%')
BEGIN
    SET @server_nm = 'DEVBCD.dbo'
END

SELECT * 
FROM @server_nm+'.tablename'
```

I want to execute the last line as using variables

```
SELECT * FROM DEVBCD.dbo.tablename
```

I am unable to do this is in SQL Server. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: And if `@@SERVERNAME not like 'DEVABCD%'` then you want `select * from NULL`?

Comment: You can't parameterize object names. This is almost always a sign a design that went a bit left of center. There are ways around this but they are clunky as all get out.

Comment: DDL cannot be parameterized since SQL queries are *compiled* not interpreted at *runtime*; you need to use *dynamic SQL* for this.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is because in production you want to get data from one database, but in a dev environment you want to get that from a different table. Maybe  looking into synonyms would be helpful. That way you can have one query that pulls data from different places depending on how you have the synonym defined.

Comment: And if you write said dynamic SQL, make sure you **sanitise** your values, and (even better) validate them.

Comment: You have to use sp_executesql to execute dynamic SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: It's a risky, dangerous path you take where the code effectively self-modifies based on something as trivial as a name. Think long and hard about this. Consider what happens when you need multiple environments  - something that is VERY common.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is you're forcing yourself down 3 part naming, when you should be building and running your SQL in the same database; then you don't need to worry about the database prefix at all.

Comment: Aside... Object names in SQL Server use the `sysname` data type which is effectively a synonym for `nvarchar(128)` with a `not null` thrown in. Trying to use `varchar(100)` for object names is wrong on two counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic SQL for this

```sql
DECLARE @server_nm sysname = N'';

IF (@@SERVERNAME LIKE 'DEVABCD%')
BEGIN
    SET @server_nm = N'DEVBCD'
END

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT *
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@server_nm) + N'.dbo.tablename;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to quote the server name, and the use of `sysname` for the variable type.

To be honest, given that this is a single command, I would probably just use a normal `IF` with two static commands:

```sql
IF (@@SERVERNAME LIKE 'DEVABCD%')
    SELECT * 
    FROM DEVBCD.dbo.tablename;
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.tablename;
```